# yfinance Crypto symbol list

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, yfinance

I am using `yfinance` in python to get crypto symbol pair prices. It gives real time data via its `yf.download(tickers=tickers, period=period, interval=interval)` function in a very nice format. I am wondering is there any function in yfinance to pull out all the supported crypto-pairs without doing any webscraping on [this](https://in.finance.yahoo.com/cryptocurrencies/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge YahooFinance uses CoinMarketCap to retrive crypto market information.

CoinMarketCap offers the API you request here: (not free)
https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/exchange/market-pairs/latest

I suggest you transfer to the Binance API. It includes the endpoint `GET /api/v1/exchangeInfo` as documented here:
https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md

Your direct endpoint would be https://api.binance.com/api/v1/exchangeInfo

Answer (score 3):

you can get crypto symbol list from yahoo.finance  only as "coin-USD"

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
num_currencies=250
resp = session.get(f"https://finance.yahoo.com/crypto?offset=0&count={num_currencies}")
tables = pd.read_html(resp.html.raw_html)               
df = tables[0].copy()
symbols_yf = df.Symbol.tolist()
print(symbols_yf[:15])
print(df.head(5))
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

"BTC-USD"works pretty well for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

you can use python-binance library

```
from binance import Client
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_binance_data(ticker, interval='4h', start='1 Jan 2018', end=None):
  client = Client()
  intervals = {
      '15m': Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_15MINUTE,
      '1h':  Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1HOUR,      
      '4h':  Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_4HOUR,
      '1d':  Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY
  }
  interval = intervals.get(interval, '4h')
#   print(f'Historical interval {interval}')
  klines = client.get_historical_klines(symbol=ticker, interval=interval, start_str=start, end_str=end)
  data = pd.DataFrame(klines)
  data.columns = ['open_time','open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume','close_time', 'qav','num_trades','taker_base_vol','taker_quote_vol', 'ignore']
  data.index = [pd.to_datetime(x, unit='ms').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in data.open_time]
  usecols=['open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'qav','num_trades','taker_base_vol','taker_quote_vol']
  data = data[usecols]
  data = data.astype('float')
  return data


client = Client()
exchange_info = client.get_exchange_info()
symbols=[s['symbol'] for s in exchange_info['symbols'] if s['status'] == 'TRADING']
ticker_list = symbols[:50]
# tiker_list = np.random.choice(symbols, size=50)
print('Number of crypto pairs: ', len(symbols))
print('First 50 pairs: ', *ticker_list)

# collect pair closes in one dataframe
coins = []
for ticker in tqdm(ticker_list):
    try:
        close_price = get_binance_data(ticker, interval='1d', start='1 Jan 2018', end='1 Jul 2022')['close'].to_dict()
        info = {'name': ticker}
        info.update(close_price)
        coins.append(info)
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        continue

coins = pd.DataFrame(coins)
# print(coins.head())
coins.head()
```

result:
[image]

if you need data of all pairs it is better use multithreading or asynchronous requests

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/general.html#id4 :

```
from binance import Client 

info = client.get_exchange_info()
symbols = [x['symbol'] for x in info['symbols']]
```

Comment: The question is specifically about yfinance... Not sure offering a completely different library answers the question...

Comment: If you know how to do it using yfinance, why not answer his question then? (or else I really don't see the point in your comment.)