# How to get all cryptocurrencies pairs with yfinance in Python?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, yfinance

I'm exploring the `yfinance` module in `Python` following this [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-i-tripled-my-return-on-bitcoin-using-mathematics-algorithms-and-python-347edd9b5625). As you can see, the author explains using BTC-USD pair but I want to know if there's some alternative to pull all cryptocurrencies pairs. Somebody asked [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67146805/yfinance-crypto-symbol-list) before but I think answer was not appropriate. Would you suggest to do some kind of web **scraping**?
Thanks in advance for any orientation, I've been a lot away from Python and I feel like I'm new again.

Comment: first I would check documentation for `yfinance` - maybe it has function to get list with all pairs or at least with all cryptocurrences. And if it does't have it then I would try to get it with web scraping - it would need to run it only once and keep results in file. Eventually I would check one of API if it has it for free - but I already have account and `API Keys` for some APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Using coinbase pro
# !pip3 install cbpro 
import cbpro
c = cbpro.PublicClient()
data_ = pd.DataFrame(c.get_products())
data_['id']
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly!